# Is there an appropriate community to ask about OSS mailing list etiquette?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about the etiquette with (Apache) mailing lists. Would this type of question be suitable for a community on Stack Exchange?

EDIT - The question is:
I got an email directly from a user, instead of from the mailing list itself. I'm a bit paranoid about security (e.g. How did they get my full email? Is this social engineering to determine if an email is active? etc.). Should I respond directly (the answer this person had is on the mailing list itself), or ignore the person?

Comment: I'd start with reading the instructions or FAQ for the Apache mailing lists.  All mailing lists have one.  If they don't, or your question isn't answered in the FAQ, why don't you just ask them directly?  Chances are good that our etiquette is stricter than theirs.

Comment: You need to specify the nature of the question a bit more before we can point you to the proper site (if any exist). That said, I'd suspect that the question of "what are the standards for ${community}" is really best answered by that community and not asking others.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 5):

At a very high level, mailing lists and activities related to cultivating a community around mailing lists, is [on topic](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51/are-mailing-lists-on-topic) at [CommunityBuilding.SE](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/).

---

That said, you'd have to provide more detail than exists in this question for it to remain open.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question.